# Use of update() for an instantiated object

Tags: python

I apologize in advance if I'm asking a somewhat obvious question, but I'm somewhat new to Python and am still figuring out the kinks of it.

I'm working on a script to search through a tree, starting at node A and (hopefully) terminating at goal node M. My work is based off of the example code provided in *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach*, [specifically this Python search script](http://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/search.py).

I run into difficulties when attempting to execute a breadth_first_search, where I get the following error:

```
...
update(self, state=state, parent=parent, action=action, 
        path_cost=path_cost, depth=0)
NameError: global name 'update' is not defined
```

I am attempting to use the [update() function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=update#dict.update) to update the state, parent, children, etc. of a node, where the code is as follows:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
        "Create a search tree Node, derived from a parent by an action."
        update(self, state=state, parent=parent, action=action, 
                path_cost=path_cost, depth=0)
        if parent:
            self.depth = parent.depth + 1
```

I've been stuck on this for a while now and am unsure how to proceed. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to help fix this problem. Thank you!

Comment: your "update" is probably part of the package "utils" which is imported on the top of the python search script. Did you import it?

Comment: specifically, the line that says `from utils import *`. if you open `utils.py` at the same link, you will see the `update` function there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update()` is a method of the builtin [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=update#mapping-types-dict) type. Note the section under which that method's documentation resides. If you were using a dictionary, let's call it `my_dict`, you'd do something like this:

```
my_dict.update(state=state, parent=parent, action=action, path_cost=path_cost, depth=0)
```

But I'm not sure you are using a dictionary for your code. The link you posted does not define the `update()` function. It must be imported with the line at the top of the example code:

```
from utils import *
```

This assumes that in `utils.py` there is a function named `update`. If that's the case, you need to include that `import` statement in your file.

Comment: D'oh. This was it. I had to do some extra searching around the AIMA site to find the utils.py file. Thanks for the info, I understand the use of update() now!

Answer (score 1):

`update()` is an instance method for dictionary objects. Unless you define the same method for your `Node`:

```
class Node:

    ...

    def update(self, ...)
```

have a dictionary within the class that can be `update`d:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.some_dict.update(...)
```

or create or `import` a function that takes a `Node` object:

```
def update(node, ...)
```

it will not be available.

Comment: Thanks for the input! This was on the right track, I failed to import the definition of update from utils.py.

Answer (score 0):

The link you have given for `update` is not a global function, but a member of dictionary, so must be called on a dictionary. If your class had one, called e.g. data

```
def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
    "Create a search tree Node, derived from a parent by an action."
    self.data.update(state=state, parent=parent, action=action, path_cost=path_cost, depth=0)
    # Note the indentation
```

---

**Edit**

Furthermore, not the code you link to also has a utils.py [here](http://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/utils.py)
This defines a global update function that will do what `Node` is trying to do:

```
def update(x, **entries):
    """Update a dict; or an object with slots; according to entries.
    >>> update({'a': 1}, a=10, b=20)
    {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
    >>> update(Struct(a=1), a=10, b=20)
    Struct(a=10, b=20)
    """
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        x.update(entries)
    else:
        x.__dict__.update(entries)
    return x
```

You probably need to get the whole svn repo, with their directory structure in order to get this working.

Comment: Bingo. I dug that up shortly after posting the question and getting a few responses. I'm a bit embarrassed for missing that!

Answer (score 0):

The update() function you linked is a method of the dict type. If your object is a subclass of dict ( or a subclass of a subclass ), you should be able to call

```
self.update()
```